# Let DataTables pagination be proper links

Tags: javascript, pagination, datatables

I would like the pagination buttons in DataTables to be proper links (having an href attribute). This makes it possible to open a specific page in a separate tab by right-clicking on the pagination button, which sometimes is very useful. It also makes it easy to get the correct url for each page, making it possible to send the url to a specific page to a friend.

Clicking the pagination buttons should of course not navigate to the url, but load the page's content via ajax, as it already does. The server side already supports delivering the contents for a specific page, so that pagination also works for users with javascript disabled. So the only thing I need is some way to tell DataTables the url to add to each of the pagination buttons. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: So, you want pagination links so you can click to open a dataTables page in separate tabs, and send a particular page to a friend, but you do not want the anchor tags to act as hyperlinks - and the dataTable should BTW work without javascript as well ..? :)

Comment: Haha :) Something like that!